# How to join table is sql?

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables which name `shoes_type` and `shoes_list`. The `shoes_type` table includes `shoes_id, shoes_size, shoes_type, date, project_id`. Meanwhile, on the `shoes_list` table, I have `shoes_quantity, shoes_id, shoes_color, date, project_id`.

I need to get the sum of **shoes_quantity** based on the **shoes_type, shoes_size, date, and also project_id**.

I get how to sum the `shoes_quantity` based on color by doing:

```
select shoes_color, sum(shoes_quantity)
from shoes_list group by shoes_color
```

Basically what I want to see is the total quantity of shoes based on the type, size, date and project_id. The type and size information are available on shoes_type table, while the quantity is coming from the shoes_list table. I expect to see something like:

```
shoes_type      shoes_size    total quantity    date         project_id
heels              5                  3         19/10/02         1
sneakers           5                  3         19/10/02         1
sneakers           6                  1         19/10/05         1
heels              7                  5         19/10/03         1
```

While for the desired result, I have tried:

```
select shoes_type, shoes_size, date, project_id, sum(shoes_quantity)
from shoes_type st
join shoes_list sl
  on st.project_id = sl.project_id
 and st.shoes_id = sl.shoes_id
 and st.date = sl.date 
group by shoes_type, shoes_size, date, project_id
```

Unfortunately, I got an error that says that the **column reference "date" is ambiguous**.

How should I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `date` column exists in both tables, so you have to specify where to select it from. Replace `date` with `shoes_type.date` or `shoes_list.date`

Answer (score 0):

Qualify all column references to remove the "ambiguous" column error:

```
select st.shoes_type, st.shoes_size, st.date, st.project_id, sum(slshoes_quantity)
from shoes_type st join
     shoes_list sl
     on st.project_id = sl.project_id and
        st.shoes_id = sl.shoes_id and
        st.date = sl.date 
group by st.shoes_type, st.shoes_size, st.date, st.project_id;
```

If you want all columns from `shoes_type`, you might find that a correlated subquery is faster:

```
select st.*,
       (select sum(slshoes_quantity)
        from shoes_list sl
        where st.project_id = sl.project_id and
              st.shoes_id = sl.shoes_id and
              st.date = sl.date
       )  
from shoes_type st;
```